# Assign "func returning pointer to struct" to var of type "func returning pointer to interface"

Tags: go

I have two functions which return pointers to two separate structs conforming to the same interface. How can I put the functions in the same map? I came up with creating wrapper functions (`getFooer` in the example) to make the types check. Is there a better way? What are the rules that make types check for the type conversion in the `getFooer` function, but not for the type conversion in the commented out line in `main`?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Fooer interface {
    Foo()
}

type A struct {
}

func (a *A) Foo() {
}

var a A = A{}

func getA() (*A) {
    return &a
}

func getFooer() (Fooer) {
    return getA()
}

func main() {
    var f func() (Fooer)
    // f = getA    // /tmp/foo.go:29:7: cannot use getA (type func() *A) as type func() Fooer in assignment
    f = getFooer
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I put the functions in the same map?

You cannot, they have different types.

> I came up with creating wrapper functions (getFooer in the example) to make the types check. Is there a better way?

Basically: No. You could modify the signature of e.g. getA to `getA() Fooer` but that would require type assertions back to `*A` if you need an A.

> What are the rules that make types check for the type conversion in the getFooer function, but not for the type conversion in the commented out line in main?

Dead simple: A function `getA() *A` hase type `func() *A` and this type is different from `func() Fooer` (no covariance). Functin types must match *literally*. You can return a `*A` as a `Fooer` because you can assign a `*A` to a variable of type `Fooer`. The getA yields a `*A` and this `*A` is assigned to the return value of `getFooer` which is a `Fooer`.